# SAS STUDIO - Error with Inner join syntax

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, sas-studio

I have 4 tables; PREFIX, FORENAME, MIDDLENAME, SURNAME. With an common column "row_num". I am taking the fuzzy matched scores out of each table, name PFX_SCR etc...

This is my current code:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE REJOIN_SCRS AS
SELECT PREFIX.ROW_NUM, PFX_SCR, FRNME_SCR, MDNME_SCR, SRNME_SCR
FROM PREFIX
INNER JOIN FORENAME, MIDDLENAME, SURNAME
USING(ROW_NUM);
QUIT;
```

I am getting this error:

```
  SELECT PREFIX.ROW_NUM, PFX_SCR, FRNME_SCR, MDNME_SCR, SRNME_SCR
86    FROM PREFIX
87    INNER JOIN FORENAME, MIDDLENAME, SURNAME
                         -
                         22
                         76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, (, '.', AS, ON.  
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
88    USING(ROW_NUM);
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
89    QUIT;
```

I don't know if I'm having a moment or if there's something wrong but I cannot figure out what is wrong with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what SQL dialect this is, but it is not valid Proc SQL syntax.

Comment: I suppose you should put an ON clause there, with the join conditions. However, FORENAME, MIDDLENAME and SURNAME are very odd table names.

Comment: @PeterClemmensen I'm working in SAS studio but have worked with SQL generally and I sometimes get the two mixed up, what is invalid here?

Comment: @jarlh is the "using()" function not synonymous with an "ON" clause. They're just labelled after the part of the name involved in testing to make life easier. I will eventually rename them.

Comment: USING is similar to ON. But an ON or USING needs its own JOIN. (FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON/USING ... JOIN t3 ON/USING ...

Comment: The USING Clause is invalid in Proc SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have an ON clause for every INNER JOIN.  So perhaps you meant something like

```
from PRFIX
inner join FORENAME on PREFIX.ROW_NUM = FORENAME.ROW_NUM
inner join MIDDLENAME on PREFIX.ROW_NUM = MIDDLENAME.ROW_NUM
...
```

You can use NATURAL joins to have SAS pick the keys to match based on which variables have the same names.

```
from PRFIX natural inner join FORENAME
natural inner join MIDDLENAME
...
```

I would think it would be easier to just use SAS syntax instead of SQL.

```
data REJOIN_SCRS;
  merge PREFIX FORENAME MIDDLENAME LASTNAME ;
  by ROW_NUM;
run;
```